# Convert newlines to <br> in a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to convert top-level newlines in a label to `<br>` so that they actually look like newlines.

E.g. the label

```
<label>Hello
there<div>who
knows</div>what's going on</label>
```

should become

```
<label>Hello<br>there<div>who
knows</div>what's going on</label>
```

I tried already scanning the top-level text nodes using `.childNodes` and replacing the text, but that leaves a `<br>` in text output, as in, it doesn't get formatted correctly and is just outputted to text that the user can see.

```
$("label[for^='answer']").each(function () {
  var thisElement = this;
  Array.prototype.slice.call($(thisElement)[0].childNodes).forEach(function (elem, index) {
    if (typeof elem.nodeValue == 'string') {
      $(thisElement)[0].childNodes[index].nodeValue = $(thisElement)[0].childNodes[index].nodeValue.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br>').replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    };
  });
});
```

How can I replace all top-level newlines with correct HTML to make them look like newlines in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** simply replace `\n` inside `<label>` because it will add `<br>`s to other elements, such as the `<div>` inside the `<label>` on your example.

You will have to iterate over the [**text nodes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) and create/insert `<br>` element in their places.

Also, to **identify the text nodes**, don't use

```
if (typeof elem.nodeValue == 'string') {
```

Use:

```
if (elem.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
```

Furthermore, see demo below.

```js
//$("label[for^='answer']").each(function () {
$("label.change-me").each(function () {
  var thisElement = this;
  Array.prototype.slice.call(thisElement.childNodes).forEach(function (elem, index) {
    if (elem.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      var lines = elem.nodeValue.split('\n');
      if (lines.length > 1) { // i.e. there are line breaks
         elem.nodeValue = lines[0];
         var nextElement = elem.nextSibling;
         for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
           elem.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('br'), nextElement);
           elem.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(lines[i]), nextElement);
         }
      }
    };
  });
});
```

```css
label { color: red }
div { color: blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="change-me">Hello
there<div>who
knows</div>what's going on</label>

<hr>

<label>Hello<br>there<div>who
knows</div>what's going on</label>

<hr>

<label class="change-me">Line-breaks inside
labels
break<div>I'm
inside
div
so
don't
break
me</div>div is over so break
me because we are
back to the label</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

What i understood by you question, you want to replace the first space with a `<br>` tag.

So i added the `splice()` function to a string to solve this

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
String.prototype.splice = function(idx, rem, str) {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};

$("label").each(function() {
  var thisText = this.innerHTML;
  var result = thisText.splice(thisText.indexOf(" "), 0, "<br>");
  this.innerHTML = result;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
Hello there
  <div>who knows</div>
what's going on
</label>
```